# Error editing connection: did not find a connection with UUID '(null)'

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager

I am a newbie to Ubuntu and I am trying to configure Ubuntu for a class. I have followed instructions that were given to me by my instructor. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from a VMWare mounted drive on a Windows 10 PC. When I first ran ifconfig -a, it did not display the connections correctly according to what should have been displayed from my instructions. I then proceeded to edit my /etc/network/interfaces file, to match the below:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

However, now I am not sure if editing the interfaces file caused this issue, but now when I go to Settings, then Network, click on "Wired" Connection, then click "Options". I see this error:

Error editing connection: Did not find a connection with UUID '(null)'

What I should see is a UI window that allows me to edit the selected connection.

Not sure if it is related, but there are no DNS settings for the selected Wired Connection either.

This is what shows:

Hardware Address

IPv4 Address

IPv6 Address

Default Route

Apparently, this is what is expected:

IP Address

Subnet Mask

Default Route

DNS

Internet is working fine though I'm having this issue. This may be for an older version of Ubuntu, however, the UI should still open after clicking on "Options".

Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone out there? I'm really stuck, and would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file **/etc/networking/interfaces** and put a **#** in front of EVERY line.  This will comment them out.  NOTE you will need to use sudo and suggest command

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

Next, stop and restart the NetworkManager.service with:

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service
```

Comment: the start and stop of the network mnager should be two separate command - most easily done on two lines.  First enter **sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service** on one line.  Then enter **sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service** on a new line

Comment: It's not working... Again shows the same error. did not find a connection with UUID